# Filtering unique values

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider the following table:

| Column_A | Column_B | Column_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UserA | NULL |
| 2 | UserB | NULL |
| 3 | UserC | 1 |
| 4 | UserA | 1 |
| 5 | UserB | NULL |
| 6 | UserB | 2 |
| 7 | UserC | 2 |

I'd like to return all rows (Column_A, Column_B, Column_C) such that either:

1. Column_C is NULL, or
2. for every unique value in Column_C, return the first row with Column_B == UserA. If no such row exists, return the first row sorted by Column_B.time_created.

| Column_A | Column_B (FK) | Column_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UserA | NULL |
| 2 | UserB | NULL |
| 4 | UserA | 1 |
| 5 | UserB | NULL |
| 6 | UserB | 2 |

Not sure how to do this in a single query.

```sql
select 
    Column_A, 
    Column_B, 
    Column_C, 
    min(case when Column_B = UserA then 0 else 1 end) as custom_order 
from Table 
where Column_B in (UserA, UserB, UserC) 
group by Column_C, Column_A 
order by Column_C nulls first, custom_order;
```

The min clause doesn't de-dupe as expected.

Comment: [Edit] the question and **only** tag the DBMS you're really using. Postgres and MySQL are very different in their capabilities, so I removed the incompatible tags. Also tag the specific version, it make make a difference too, especially in the case you're using MySQL.

Comment: What column defines the order in a numerical, timestamp-/date-ish or lexicographical way? (Words like "first" etc. aren't really good for that...)

Comment: what is column_B.Time_Created?  It's not in your table columns defined...

Comment: Column_B is an FK column to a user table. Each user row has a time_created field that should be used for choosing the row to return when Column_B != UserA,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have analytic functions available...

I break this apart let's get all the null values 1st..
Then union in the non nulls based on the order you want using an analytic (row_number), an embedded case expression, and two order bys.

```
SELECT Column_A, Column_B, Column_C, 0 as RN
FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN_C is null

UNION ALL

SELECT Column_A, Column_B, Column_C, RN
FROM (
  SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by A.column_C Order by case A.column_B when 'UserA' then 0 else 1 end, U.Time_Created) rn
  FROM Table A
  INNER JOIN user U
    on U.Column_B = A.Column_B
  WHERE A.Column_C is not null) B
WHERE RN = 1
```

the whole user join is based on a comment not the question.    it assumes table joins to user on column_B

We use a case statement to handle ordering the 'UserA's first and then time created.  so if you have two "userA"'s the first created will be first as well.

Comment: I tried the second half of the query, but get an error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "order"
LINE 1: ..., ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by A.Column_C, order by c...

Comment: Nvmd, no comma between partition by and order by. Thanks for your help, checking the query now.

Comment: @polestar  glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks xQbert for your help. Updated the answer to fix a few things:

1. No comma between partition and order
2. Filter by user_ids in each subquery - there may be users in the table we don't care about.

'''

```
SELECT Column_A, Column_B, Column_C, 0 as RN
FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN_C is null and Column_B in (UserA, UserB, UserC)

UNION ALL

SELECT Column_A, Column_B, Column_C, RN
FROM (
  SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by A.column_C Order by case A.column_B when 'UserA' then 0 else 1 end, U.Time_Created) rn
  FROM Table A
  INNER JOIN user U
    on U.Column_B = A.Column_B
  WHERE A.Column_C is not null and ColumnB in (userA, userB, UserC)) B
WHERE RN = 1
```

'''

Comment: Glad it all worked out for you.  Remember; when eating an elephant, take one bite at a time.  That's all I did here was break apart the pieces and put it back together.  We could probably avoid the union; but as they are "Fast" I didn't see a reason not to break out the query into understandable segments.